# How to implement conditional border formatting in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to force cells `B, C, D, E` to have an upper border IFF cell `A` is not empty.

[image]

How can I do this ?

Comment: use [Conditional Formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html)

Comment: If the cell is empty (`=$A2=""`) then apply a `None` border to those cells

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnA, HOME > Styles  - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., Use a formula to determine which cells to format, enter:

```
=$A1<>""
```

in Format values where this formula is true:. Select Format..., apply Border (top border), OK, OK. Ensure Applies to is set to  `=$B:$E`, OK.